# JQuery hover animate

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Jquery Newbie question:

Here is my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/T8TNP/

Here is what I need to accomplish:  http://www.detailpaintinginc.com/index.php

Im having a problem with the hover:

You will notice that the lower color boxes all change opacity on hover.

The opacity for the specific child div (with class"box") should change to .5 The way it stands now all of the children's opacity is changing even if I only hover over one child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just apply the effect directly to the divs instead of targeting the parent?

```
$('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": .5
    }, 50)
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, 50)
});
```

Also, your width on the .wrap element was too narrow which is why the boxes weren't appearing side by side.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/T8TNP/6/)**.

Comment: Why not using CSS instead ? Check my answer below :)

Comment: Well, in that case you have to learn in which cases Javascript (and jQuery) is required, and in which cases it isn't. Here, it isn't required at all, and a CSS solution would perform way better than a Javascript one :) BTW, it spells `jQuery` :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/U4dyE/ You don't need Javascript to do this effect, look at the code :)

HTML code

```
<div id="container">
     <div class="wrap">
         <div class="box"></div>
         <div class="box"></div>
     </div>
</div>​
```

CSS code

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;    
}

/* DRY :) */
.wrap, .box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px; 
    float: left;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}


.box {
    background-color: red;

    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    /* animation for "mouse out" */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;  /* FF4+ */
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;  /* IE10 */
         -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
            transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.box:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    /* animation for "mouse in" */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;  /* FF4+ */
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;  /* IE10 */
         -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
            transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

​

​JS code

```
// absolutely none ! :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper needs to be a bit wider for the boxes to have room on the same line. Also you should run the hover function on each box, not their parent, to get them to react individually:

```
$(function () {
    $('.wrap .box').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({'opacity': 0.5}, 50);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({'opacity': 1}, 50);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/T8TNP/7/